# Skipping cancelled dequeue attempt with queue not closed

Tags: tensorflow

I have reading data for training as follow.

```
def read_data(batch_size, input_shape, file_src):
  reader = tf.TextLineReader()
  _, value = reader.read(file_src)
  filename, label, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box6, box7, box8 = tf.decode_csv(value, [[''], [''], [''],[''],[''],[''],[''],[''],[''],['']], ' ')
  boxes = tf.transpose(tf.stack([tf.strings.to_number(box1,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box2,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box3,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box4,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box5,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box6,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box7,tf.dtypes.float32),tf.strings.to_number(box8,tf.dtypes.float32)]))
  image_file = tf.read_file(filename)
  height, width, channels_num = input_shape
  rgb_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file, channels=channels_num)
  rgb_image_float = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(rgb_image, tf.float32)
  resized_images = tf.image.resize_images(rgb_image_float, [height, width])
  resized_images.set_shape(input_shape)

  min_after_dequeue = 30000
  capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
  image_batch, label_batch, boxes_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([resized_images, label, boxes], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
                                                    min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)

  return image_batch, label_batch, boxes_batch
```

When I run in sess, I have such error.

```
coordinator = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=session, coord=coordinator)
for i in range(config.train.steps):
     curr_step, curr_learning_rate, curr_loss, curr_opt_loss = session.run([global_step_rec, learning_rate, loss, opt_loss])
```

The exact error is

```
2019-11-13 10:54:40.738358: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:285] _1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue: Skipping cancelled dequeue attempt with queue not closed
FailedPreconditionError: FailedPr...onError()
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to adjust `min_after_dequeue` and `capacity` according to own data. Say, I have 1000 dataset, then `min_after_dequeue` is not necessary to be high and need to be set lower than 1000. It is how much data is left in the queue so that next batch of data is retrieved from the buffer. If enough data is left in the queue, it is ok. The capacity is max number of data in the queue.